# MergeError: right can only have one index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe df (applicationstartdate as a index) and a series app_3M, I want to merge together.

The series looks like:

```
New_ID  applicationstartdate
1001    2021-02-28              0.0
1003    2021-01-31              0.0
        2021-02-28              2.0
        2021-03-31              2.0
        2021-04-30              1.0
Name: N_App_3M, dtype: float64
```

I want to merge the last (numerical) column to df on New_ID and applicationstartdate.

I tried:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df, app_3M, direction="nearest", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

which resulted in:

> MergeError: right can only have one index

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: reset the index and feed the column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert first level to column and if need also merge by `New_ID` add parameter `by='New_ID'` to [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), for sorting add [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df, 
                   app_3M.reset_index(level=0).sort_index(), 
                   direction="nearest", 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   by='New_ID')
```

Comment: ValueError: right keys must be sorted

Comment: @StanislavJirák - use `app_3M.reset_index(level=0).sort_index()`